# UITextView Font Setting

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am having a problem in UITextView. following is my code.

```
UITextView *txtDescription = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 50, 290, 100)];
//txtDescription.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:17.0];
txtDescription.delegate = self;
txtDescription.tag = 2;
//txtDescription.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txtDescription.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
UILabel *lblPlaceholder = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 5, 200, 30)];
//lblPlaceholder.text = @"Description (Required)";
//lblPlaceholder.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
//lblPlaceholder.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:17];
[txtDescription addSubview:lblPlaceholder];
[scrollView addSubview:txtDescription];
```

when i am tring to set Font, AutocorrectionType or add any subview to my textview it is giving following error.

UIKit`-[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) selectionView]

Please have a look.

I am using same code for 2 months but from today it is giving this kind of error.

I am not getting any solution. Please help me.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You're sure that's the full error? It should be some additional text before / after. Also try adding a breakpoint before the code, running it line by line and check where it throws the exception.

Comment: What Text Field delegate methods are you using?

Comment: yes i have tried this code with break points. Then it get crashed on set font line of TextView and when i am adding any subview to this then it is surely getting crashed.

Comment: Delegate methods : - 

(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView 

and 

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView

But it is crashed on creating this view not when cliking on this.
And yes one thing more this code is not crashing on iOS 5 simulator.
Thank You

Comment: You're sure the font exists? Also try using [txtDescription setFont:] though I don't think that would be the problem.

Comment: Mind I ask why you're adding a text field to a text view as subview? o.O

Comment: Yes, you are right ZSolt. Problem is somewhere else. I am running the code on device it is running fine. but not in iOS 6.1 simulator.

Comment: can u pls remove the placeholder label and check

Comment: I am unable to understand why some so called intelligent and smart people always show eagerness to give negative marks to some person.

Thank You. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no reason for that code to crash. So I think the problem has to be elsewhere.

I've tried this and it doesn't crash for me:

```
UITextView *txtDescription = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 50, 290, 100)];
[txtDescription setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
[txtDescription setText:@"This is TEXT"];
[txtDescription setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[self.view addSubview:txtDescription];
```

This also works:

```
txtDescription.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];
txtDescription.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Do you have the font?